# How to use boto3 waiters to wait RDS instance to be in availble state inorder to stop

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, boto3

I am confused with the usage of boto3 waiters. I want to stop the rds instances which are in **available** state. Before stopping i need to make some modificaitions( MultiAZ deployed instances to none). So i want to wait until the instance get modified and to be in available state. How can i come over this.Here is my script:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('rds')


dbmultiAZ=[]

def lambda_handler(event,context):
 response=client.describe_db_instances()

 for i in response['DBInstances']:
    if i['DBInstanceStatus'] == 'available':
        dbmultiAZ.append(i['DBInstanceIdentifier'])


        for j in dbmultiAZ:
            if i['MultiAZ']==True:
                response1 = client.modify_db_instance(
                    DBInstanceIdentifier=i['DBInstanceIdentifier'],
                    ApplyImmediately=True,
                    MultiAZ=False
                    )
                dbmultiAZ.append(i['DBInstanceIdentifier'])
            else:
                dbmultiAZ.append(i['DBInstanceIdentifier'])



for z in dbmultiAZ:
        waiter = client.get_waiter('db_instance_available')
        waiter.wait(
            DBInstanceIdentifier=z  )
        response2 = client.stop_db_instance(
            DBInstanceIdentifier=z
            )
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, but you have a for-loop with `j` in the middle, but `j` isn't used. Also, the bottom block of code is incorrectly indented, so it isn't part of the `lambda_handler` (at least the way it is shown here). Try to always use a 4-space indent to make them clear.

Answer (score -2):

Using waiters inside of lambda is anti-pattern for serverless.  Instead, you should utilize step functions to have the following:

Step 1: Create RDS

Step 2: Check if finished

Step 3: Move on if finished, Recheck if not

Step 4 ....